# QTableView, Multiple Columns with One Header

Tags: c++, qt, user-interface

I am looking for a way to display one column header across three columns in a QTableView.

This seems like it should be possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[void QTableView::setSpan ( int row, int column, int rowSpanCount, int columnSpanCount )](https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qtableview.html#setSpan)