# Spanning a Header across Two Columns in a QTableView

Tags: c++, qt

I have a QTableView. I want three columns to share a common header.

My approach has been to resize column3 to the size of col1+col2+col3, and then resize column2 to size of col1+col2 and resize colmumn1 the same way.

When I attempt to use the resizeSection() method, I end up with the middle column disappearing behind the overlap of the left and right columns.

From my experimenting, this is not a trivial problem.

I have looked at ["How can I span the headers in my QTableView?" on Qt's Technical FAQ](https://wiki.qt.io/Technical_FAQ#How_can_I_span_the_headers_in_my_QTableView_.3F), but it was only of minimal help, mostly in understanding the problem.

What is the easiest and most straight forward way of accomplishing this?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [QTableView, Multiple Columns with One Header](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11421153/qtableview-multiple-columns-with-one-header)

Answer (score 1):

The approach I am taking is to Lay a new QTableView ontop of the QTableView, with geometry set to the header size, so as to use this as a sort of 'header mask' and connect it to the one beneath it with signals and slots.